# Evaluating an integral using the Fubini Theorem.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[image]

I want to calculate $\int_{B}x^2z$ and for this I have done the following $\int_{B}x^2z=\int_{A}(\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta)^2(\rho\cos\phi)\rho^2\sin\phi=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{a}(\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta)^2(\rho\cos\phi)\rho^2\sin\phi d\rho 
d\phi d\theta$.

Is this argument correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, that looks fine to me.

Comment: @B.Mehta How can I calculate this integral?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{a}(\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta)^2(\rho\cos\phi)\rho^2\sin\phi \,d\rho 
\,d\phi \,d\theta \\
=&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{a}
\rho^4\sin^3\phi\cos^2\theta\cos\phi
\,d\rho \,d\phi \,d\theta\\
=&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^2\theta\,d\theta
\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^3\phi\cos\phi\,d\phi
\int_{0}^{a}\rho^4\,d\rho
\end{align}
which should be easy to evaluate.

Comment: I know how to calculate all but $\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^3\phi\cos\phi d\phi$. I have tried to call $u=\cos\phi$ and make a variable change, can this be done? The integral gives me zero.

Comment: Draw a graph of the integrand...

Comment: Can you see why the integral *should* be zero?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: No worries, hope this helped!